# What is the name of the control MS-Access creates when generating a form with 1-M?

Tags: ms-access

If you create a form on a table that has 1-M relationship with another table, MS-Access creates the form containing the fields of the "1" side as text boxe, etc. and for the M-Side, a tabular structure is created.

What is the name of the control representing the tabular structure? (it is some kind of a list but it is not like the list you select from the tool box!). This control does not have a click event. Why? It only has ON ENTER and ON LEAVE events, so how to capture the current row?

[image]

Comment: Relevant links: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-subform-c59387f9-73aa-4082-82cb-5d29ef04299f and http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Answer (score 1):

The object next to the question mark is a Subform/Subreport Container Control. As its name implies, it is a container that holds other objects which can be a table, query, form, or report. This control is also available for selection from the 'toolbox'.

Best to give the container control a name different from the object it holds, like ctrDocuments.

What do you mean by 'capture' the current row? A row is not referenced, fields and controls are referenced. Several ways to approach referencing fields and controls (if a form or report) of the dependent object. How depends on where you want to run the code. In a query? In the main form events? In the subform events? For example code in Click event of a button on the main form could be like:
`strDoc = Me.ctrDocuments.DocPK`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so if I waned to know the current highlighted row in the subform when the user presses a key such as "Update", what code could I use (assuming the control is called ctrDocuments, for example)? I can do that with the lower control which is a List using a _Click event and the collection List() of the control. but I am not sure how to get the selected row in the 2nd control. Thanks.

Comment: See revised answer. A record is committed to table when one of 3 things happens: 1. close table, query, or report; 2. move to another record; 3. run code to save `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`. There is no need to reference a specific record row to save.

Comment: Thanks again, but the sub-report control does not allow for referencing the column property directly and it does not have Items() collection either!

Comment: Yes, it is possible to reference fields of the subform. By 'subform' I mean the form object held by the container. What exactly do you want to do? What do you mean by Items() collection? Did you mean Item() method?

Comment: Correction to earlier comment - 1. close table, query, or form (not report)

Comment: To clarify the point, let us say the user selects the 2nd row in the sub-report and they go and hit a keys such as "Print" (not shown). The program needs to know the data on the second row of the sub-report. I was under the impression that one can get the selected row data or at least a row selected event where one could programmatically capture the key, but the other answer suggests, this is not possible! Thank you for you help.

Comment: You mean 'subform' not 'subreport'? Yes, reference to fields or controls will return the second row values because that is the row that has focus in the subform. Referencing fields and controls is really the only way to pull data. So if pulling values from record is what you mean by 'capture row' then yes, can capture row.

Comment: Could you please provide the syntax for this. For example ME.SubFormName.?(?). Thx

Answer (score 1):

It is a form within the main form AKA sub-form. Although it appears to be a grid-view (Access call it datasheet view), it isn't. Therefore **it does not have row based events**. However, the sub-form has all the events like a normal form would.

There are few limitations in this "dataSheetView", no other controls are visible except text boxes. **If you need a button**, you must have a textbox with click events. Ideally place the textbox as first/last column so you have your action buttons.

Access also has a "ContinuousFormView" which can be decorated like a gridview with all custom controls. Again, they are forms and do not have row based events. Only control based or form based.